# cannot make react-leaflet to update markers dynamically: it gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'leafletElement' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-leaflet

I have the table and I have the react-leaflet component drawn in a single tab (rc-tabs). They are not connected but Redux.
I have rows in the table with coordinates. When I click on the row, coordinates are passed into Tab component and then via props are moved to map and are drawn.

Well, they should be - when I pass the whole array of rows with coordinates - they are drawn just fine, but when I am passing single values - I meet some troubles.

I have testsData - where all rows are stored and, depending on what row is clicked, I find the index. When I pass to Map testData[0] - it is drawn fine. When I try to change the index with the help of redux - I got an error. I use approach with index and before that I used another - where I passed the whole row into the props - no luck.

```
 const Map = (props) => {

    return (

        <LeafMap
            preferCanvas={true}
            zoom={zoom}
            style={mapHeightStyle}>
            <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                       attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
            />

                {props.tests.map(item => (
                    <Marker

                    className={item.id}
                    key={item.id}
                    position={item.coordinates[0], item.coordinates[1]}

                    }
                >
                    </Marker>

                ))}
            </FeatureGroup>
        </LeafMap>
    )
};
```

And here is my Tabs component (I cut some code!)

```
const Tabs = () => {

    let clickedTestRow = useSelector(state => state.deviceTestsTable.rowClicked);
    let testsData = useSelector(state => state.fetchTestsData.testsData);
    let [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
    let clickedTestRowIndex = 0;

    if (Object.keys(clickedTestRow).length) {
        clickedTestRowIndex = testsData.findIndex(x => x.id === clickedTestRow.id);

        if (!markers.includes(clickedTestRow)) {
            setMarkers(testsData[clickedTestRowIndex]]);
        }
    }



    // initial value - showing the first row on map

useEffect(() => {
        if (testsData.length > 0) {
            setMarkers([testsData[clickedTestRowIndex]]);
        }
    }, [testsData]);


    let props = {
        tests: markers
    };


    const tabs = [
        {key: 'Map', component: <Map {...props}/>, disabled: false},
    ];
```

What am I missing? Every time I have TypeError: Cannot read property 'leafletElement' of undefined

Comment: It would be easier if you could make a demo. It is a bit tricky right now to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This may be incomplete, but in your first block of code you use `test.props.map`, but there is no `test` variable in scope. Should this be `props.test.map`?

Comment: @rfestag and kboul sorry, props.tests.map - I have a variable here for shortance and on stackoverflow I cut it for clarity. My mistake. As I've said - it is ok when I show many items. It is ok when I show single item. When I am passing another single item via redux it won't draw. I cannot make a demo - it would be too large to optimize my code to make it a demo(

Comment: When you say you are passing in a "single item", do you mean an array with one element? Or are you sometimes passing in an array and other times an object? Also, you don't show that you are using a key property on the Marker element. Does each item have some key/id property you can use?

Comment: @rfestag Every time I am iterating over the props.tests with map. I always pass arrays of objects. I changed my code a little - I have a key for every item. The main issue is in passing new array instead of this - if the array is prepared everything draws fine, if array is change on the fly - it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Sorry, this was really annoying - the problem was in my

```
mapRef.current.leafletElement.getBounds().contains(markerRef.current[item.id].leafletElement.getLatLng()))
```

where I referred to item, to see if it in within bound. For some reason leaflet didn't like it when I was update the state and data dynamically. I feel so sorry to have this error - I didn't type it above, because I was sure the problem is in another place...

Thanks, @rfestag and @kboul for comments!